# in Powershell how can I convert int32 to System.Nullable[int]

Tags: powershell

I am getting a type conversion error in my PowerShell function. the Function is using a web API to get the information back but my PowerShell function receives the info as Int32.

```
function Get-NetworkInfo
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]$NetworkAddress = $null,
        $Subnet = $null,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] 
        [int[]]$VLan = $null,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]$NetworkName = $null,
        [ValidateSet("NONE", "ENTERPRISE", "BUILDINPLACE", "ENTERPRISE_WIFI")]
        [string]$DHCPType = $null
    )

    BEGIN
    {
        $url = "http://Server1:8071/DataQueryService?wsdl" 
        $proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $url 
    }
    PROCESS
    {
        $proxy.AdvancedDiscoveredNetworkSearch($networkAddress,$subnet,$vlan,$(if($vlan){$True}Else{$false}),$networkName,$dhcpType,$(if($dhcpType){$True}Else{$false}))
    }
    END
    {

    }
}
```

ERROR:

```
C:\Scripts> Get-NetworkInfo -vlan 505 Cannot convert argument "vlan", with value: "System.Int32[]", for "AdvancedDiscoveredNetworkSearch" to type "System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]": "Cannot convert the "System.Int32[]" value of type "System.Int32[]" to type "System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]"."
At C:\Get-NetworkInfo.ps1:23 char:163
+ ... pe){$True}Else{$false}))
+                    ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Comment: What is your question? You are passing array `int[]` where `Nullable<int>` is expected. You probably shouldn't have it declared as array in the first place. Or loop over array if you have to call it for each element.

Comment: The intention is to accept an array I just haven't done the logic for looping over the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you've declared `$vlan` to be of type `[int[]]` - that is, an *array* of `Int32`'s.

Just change the parameter declaration to `[int]$vlan = $null` and you should be fine.

---

Additionally, your `if(){}else{}` constructs can be much simpler.

For `$vlan`, just do `$([bool]$vlan)`, a value of 0 will default to `$false`.

For the `$DHCPType` you can do the same, or use `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty()` to see if the user actually passed any argument: `$(-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($DHCPType))`